# How to put 52 OOP card class in a list without declaring them one by one?

Tags: python, oop

I wanted to create a card game, but I found it really hard when it comes to creating a list that contains each card class.

```
class Cards:
    def __init__(self, type, number):
        self.type = type
        self.number = number

stack = []
for i in range(13):
    card = Cards("spade",i)
    stack.append(card)
```

Apparently this is not correct but just to show what I'm trying to do. I want to use the OOP to create a card class and create 52 object which each representing a card and put them into the stack. Because in the later stage some numbers of each card are used to do some simple calculation, therefore a seperate number assigned to each card which i could use later is necessarry. Can anyone suggest me a way to achieve my goal or fix this code to make it works?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I already changed my wording and improve my question, hopefully now you can better see what i'm asking

Comment: _Apparently this is not correct_ What exactly do you mean?  **How** is it not correct?  What does this code not do, that you need it to do?

Comment: @John Gordon provided a very good answer. I'd add that instead of creating the cards as you do, I'd create a class Deck, and then put the code that generates the deck in the `__init__` method (or a custom initialize method). This way you have everything fully encapsulated. Maybe later you want to instantiate this deck inside a Player class, and that player is instantiated (together with other player instances) inside a Game class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two nested loops, one for the suit and one for the rank.

```
stack = []
for suit in ["heart", "diamond", "club", "spade"]:
    for i in range(13):
        stack.append(Cards(suit, i))
```

This loop will make 13 hearts, then 13 diamonds, etc.

Comment: Oh its solved now, I think I was wrong because I was directly using print(stack[1]) rather then print(stack[1].number) thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to create 52 diferentent variables, you can store your objects in a list or a dictionary.

```
# You need at least one attribute charactering each of your objects
# I am assuming you have an individual ID  -> range(52)
# However these could be just your card value -> [card_1_value_1, ..., card_52_value]

# In a list:
lst = [Card(id = i) for i in range(52)]  # list comprenhension

# In a dictionary:
dict = {i:Card(id = i) for i in range(52)}  # dictionary comprenhension
```

If you really need to define these as variables you could use the exec() function, but I strongly suggest not to do this as is it not a good praxis.

```
for i in range(52):
    exec(f'variable_{i} = Card(id={i})')
```

Comment: But if you create a dictionary like this you won't be able to compare for exmaple ‘spade 5’ and ’heart 8‘. because they are just in a list and defined as a string.